# Removing off-topic questions or leaving them?

Tags: discussion

Should we delete off-topic questions like [If my aunt remarried, am I related to her spouse's family?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/14389/1006) or downvote them into oblivion?

Answer (score 3):

I'm inclined to close and downvote them, and let the [Roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/215590) take their deletion out of our hands.

During the time that such questions stay on our site they act as "good" examples of what not to ask.

Comment: I agree, but wish that people wouldn't answer crap questions, potentially taking them out of the reach of the Roomba.